# Irradiance Map Equation What is "dω"?

Tags: lighting

Link to paper : [Irradiance and Incoming Radiance | lawrence.edu](http://www2.lawrence.edu/fast/GREGGJ/CMSC420/chapter21/Irradiance.html)

> Using a shader to compute En

[image]

> Computing En as described above is a very compute intensive operation,
>   because we have to compute the integral over the cube map for each new
>   direction vector n that we want to work with. At the same time, the
>   details for different values of n are highly repetitive. This suggests
>   that we should enlist the aid of shaders to compute this mapping for
>   us. Here is the outline of a strategy that makes it possible to do
>   this.
>
> 1. Use OpenGL to render a two dimensional square centered at the origin
>      with sides of length 2. This square represents one of the sides of our
>      cubical irradiance map. Given the mapping above we can map any point
>      (x , y) on the square to a direction vector n.
> 2. We render the square to
>      a framebuffer with dimensions size by size pixels, where size is the
>      desired size of our irradiance cube map texture.
> 3. In the fragment
>      shader, we translate the interpolated fragment positions we are given
>      into direction vectors n and construct loops that sum over the six
>      faces of the environment map:
>
> When rendering is done, we convert the image in the frame buffer to a
>   texture for use by our irradiance cube map.

I understand that Li is color at i. ωi is the direction of incoming light.

However I do not understand what dωi is.

Paper describes it as...

> Computing the solid angle dωi subtended by a particular texel is a
>   little more involved. Texels near the center of the texture subtend a
>   somewhat larger angle, while texels near the corner take up a smaller
>   solid angle when we map the cube texture onto a sphere. Here is a
>   reference that explains how to compute the solid angle correctly from
>   the positions xi and yi.

However I am not following words to understand what it means.

Comment: Are you familiar with differentials in calculus, like $dy/dx$ and such? Are you familiar with the concept of solid angle?

Comment: @NathanReed yes I am familiar with dy/dx but I am not familiar with concept of solid angle.

Comment: @NathanReed ok soI did more research and I think I have better understanding of solid angle. Solid angle ranges from 0~4 pi. But what does differential of solid angle of the normal vector at "i" mean?

Comment: It looks like an integral that's been quantified.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$E_n$ is illuminance (or irradiance), $L_i$ is luminance (or radiance) in direction $\omega_i$ and $d\omega$ is differential solid angle.

**TL;DR**: $d\omega_i$ is the area of a pixel in the cubemap projected onto the unit sphere.

And then a longer explanation (:

Solid angle is essentially the projected area of an object on a unit sphere and has unit of steradians (sr). Entire unit sphere has surface area of $4\pi$ and hemisphere has the area of $2\pi$, which comes up a lot in lighting calculations due to integrals over spheres and hemispheres respectively.

If you would want to calculate solid angle for an object and point $p$, you would project the object on the unit sphere at $p$ and calculate the area of the projection. Further the object is from $p$ smaller the solid angle gets. As an example, we can calculate solid angle for Sun as seen from the Earth. We know that Sun has about 0.52 degrees [subtended angle](https://er.jsc.nasa.gov/seh/math30.html) from Earth, so we can calculate that the solid angle is:
$$2\pi*(1-Cos(0.52/2))\simeq0.00006469sr$$

So the differential solid angle is just an infinitesimally small solid angle. If you would numerically integrate over a sphere ($4\pi$ steradians) by taking $N$ uniform samples on the sphere, your $d\omega$ would be $4\pi/N$. With integrals $N$ goes to infinity, while with numerical approximation of the integral $N$ is some "sufficiently large" number.

However, in this paper you refer to they perform integration by rendering to a cubemap at $p$ and then iterating through all the rendered pixels. But because these pixels are rendered onto planes (cubemap faces), their projection on the unit sphere isn't constant, so $d\omega$ needs to be weighted by the position in the rendered image, which they explain in your second quote:

> Computing the solid angle dωi subtended by a particular texel is a
>   little more involved. Texels near the center of the texture subtend a
>   somewhat larger angle, while texels near the corner take up a smaller
>   solid angle when we map the cube texture onto a sphere.